# orchard cms module compilation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, orchardcms

I am developing an Orchard module, it has a Route within it. Under precompiled compilation it 404s, if I delete the bin dir (dynamic compilation) the Route then works. Any ideas what is going on here? The dll is in the App_Data/Dependencies dir, sometimes with a .deleted copy as well. If I decompile the assemblies the contents is correct. Have not seen this behavior before, can install other modules of my own and routes work fine. Using the latest Orchard 1.5.1 binary install.

**UPDATE**

Cut over to the latest changeset on the 1.x branch and everything is all good? Have got a zip, will try and log a bug on codeplex

Comment: which is fine because I want web api etc

Comment: Try looking in AppData\Logs for a cause of those 404s. 404 for a correct route in Orchard usually means sth wrong is happening. It may be some reference loading issue etc. Eg. your module precompiled .dll might require version of some dll other than the one available.

Comment: @PiotrSzmyd I'll go back and take a look. Working from 1.x now, because I would like to use WebApi anyway, and everything is fine.

Comment: we're on a pretty tight deadline so don't have too much time to muck around

Comment: Ok, will try to investigate but if it's fixed in 1.x then it's good:) Most probably it's all about referenced dll version mismatch somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after installing VS2012 today. Using Orchard 1.5.1 my custom modules would not be loaded and I was getting 404s for all of the routes in my custom modules after re-compiling. I found that the references to System.Web.Mvc had changed to version 4.0.0.0. Re-adding the reference using version 3.0.0.0 solved the problem for me.

An alternative would be to upgrade to Orchard version 1.6 which uses MVC4, but this was not an option yet in my case as it requires .Net Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first try to delete (or rename) the complete App_Data/Dependencies folder, it will be rebuilt on startup.

Comment: With the same problem unfortunately